# REST API and polymorphism

Tags: java, angularjs, json, rest, polymorphism

I have classes hierarchy in JAVA  that should be available through a rest API for an angularJS SPA application (the data persisted in PostgreSQL DB)

the classes hierarchy looks as follows:

- PERSON BASE ABSTRACT CLASS  contains name and and age
- CHILD EXTENDS PERSON contains favorite TV show
- PARENT EXTENDS PERSON  contains **a list of children**
- GRANDPARENT EXTENDS PERSON contains **a list of parents**

The UI looks like an hierarchy tree, where you can view all the data and edit it.

### I could thought of three ways to model this:

1. one endpoint with hierarchy /grandparent:id/parents:id/children:id
   example
   POST /grandparent/1/parents/2/children
   in order to create a new child

**PROS:** more readable, more restful
**CONS:** complex to implement, when I edit a child, I don't care about all the hierarchy at most I need the direct parent in order to create it,
but for editing, child ID will be sufficient to find the it in the DB

2. three endpoints : /grandparents:id, /parents:id, /children:id
   POST /children?parentID=2

**PROS:** ?
**CONS:** a lot of duplication

3.one endpoint /people (in the request/response JSON, use type field to denote the class and a parentID field.

POST /people
{
  name ..
  type : child
  parentId : 2
}

**PROS:** 
more polymorphic
**CONS:** less restful?

what do you think?

Comment: I like the polymorphic (almost JSON-RPCish) one.  REST is only good up until a certain point IMHO.  Especially when sometimes you have to pull parameters from a url and other times (or at the same time) the payload.   Finally... What makes you so sure taking a vote will give the the correct answer?  Two words: Presidential election.  :)

Comment: Why do you think the third one is "less RESTful"? It's either RESTful, or its not. URL signature is an orthogonal problem to RESTfulness.

Comment: You can combine 2 together having the `/people/:id` endpoint and `/people/:id/parents`. Then you can easily reference everyone (sure you can add another endpoint `/people/:id/grandparents` but it seems redundant IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just have a 'people' endpoint, and a 'person' endpoint.

The people endpoint would return **a list** of person_ids fitting a criteria. For instance 'has_children' = true would return all parents. 'has_parents' = false would return all test tube babies, etc etc etc.

The 'person' endpoint would return details about the specific person, given a specific id. Here you would see eye color, gender, a list of children person_ids, a list of parent person_ids, perhaps a list of grandchildrens person_id. Any other details about the person would be here.

You might want to consider refactoring the Java code if the extended classes don't add any significant functionality that you couldn't get simply from a person class.

Essentially you are dealing with person 'nodes' here.

Check out  Graph Commons API maybe much of your work is done for you.