# Polymorphism and tree structre

Tags: java, database, hibernate, oop, polymorphism

After asking the following question before : [rest api and polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38797797/rest-api-and-polymorphism?noredirect=1#comment64970838_38797797)

I wonder maybe my whole db schema and class structure is wrong.
the current structure is:

- PERSON BASE ABSTRACT CLASS  contains name and and age
- CHILD EXTENDS PERSON contains favorite TV show
- PARENT EXTENDS PERSON  contains **a list of children**
- GRANDPARENT EXTENDS PERSON contains **a list of parents**

In db the tables organized in table for each subtype

I thought of maybe refactoring the classes since the subtybes don't add any valuable fields, except to list of children/parents to this, only one class that include all the 
fields:

```
 @Entity
 class Person{
  @ManyToOne 
  private Person parent;   //parent==null is a grandparent

  @OneToMany
  private List<Person> children;
}
```

However, the problem with this is that in my business logic, parent child and grandparent do have different behaviors, and this way its harder to distinguish
furthermore, a child parent can not be a grandparent.

Another problem is, say I am staying with the current class structure
separating the classes doesn't really helps me because I am using a service layer
and I have no way to no which service class I need, example :

```
class PeopleController extends Controller { 
    public Result savePerson() {
      Person p = objectMapper.readValue.. // deseralizes to correct subtype
      // saving logic is different for each subtype, hence I need to 
      // find correct repository for this subtype but I don't want to use 
      // instance of or switch case, but to use polymorphism, but can't think
```

of a way without implementing active record which I don't want
         }
    }

Comment: Aren't grandparents ... just parents of parents? So, why do you think you need to treat them special? And how you treat the parents of grandparents?
Meaning: be really precise about your abstractions; don't rely on properties that are that easy to be seen from a different point of view. And, you sure that one Person has only one Parent-person? Interesting idea, when you think about it. Maybe, in our times it is no longer appropriate to assume that there is a father-parent-person and a mother-parent-person. But most likely: most people would have exactly two parent persons in their live.

Comment: In other words, coming from the "domain driven design" side: you should really spent some more thinking about your domain; and the model that you want to be using an implement.

Comment: @GhostCat  , in my project domain they should have one parent, it's fine.. "Aren't grandparents ... just parents of parents? So, why do you think you need to treat them special?" - because in my business logic, they have different behaivour in a lot of method, furthermore, a child's parent can not be a grandparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determination of *type* can be completely determined based on state and it doesn't require the use of polymorphism as your question hasn't provided any real basis for using it in the first place.  The attributes you've defined as collecting seem reasonable for all `Person`s.

1. A `Parent` is any person that contains a *non-empty* child set.
2. All `Person` instances constitute a `Child`, but for this exercise it could imply any person that contains an *empty* child set.
3. A `GrandParent` is any person that is a `Parent`, but also requires that at least one of its instances in the child set be a `Parent`.

With that in mind, we could consider restructuring the data model as follows.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  // any person can have this, not just children imo :)
  private String favoriteShow;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private Set<Person> children;

  @ManyToOne
  private Person parent;

  @Transient
  public boolean isChild() {
    return children == null || children.isEmpty();
  }

  @Transient
  public boolean isParent() {
    return !isChild();
  }

  @Transient
  public boolean isGrandParent() {
    return isParent() 
         && children.stream().filter( Person::isParent ).count() > 0;
  }
}
```

Even with this approach, your logic can branch based on the boolean transient method checks.  There are ways you can optimize these methods of course but I wouldn't be too worried about that as these checks are already well optimized on JDK8.

The benefit here though is you can simply have a `Person` service your controller interacts with and most likely a `Person` repository since the data is aligned as one type.

I realize your saving logic is different per type, but my question is does it really have to be different?  Perhaps more in-depth reasoning why these need to be split can help give us more context.

Comment: You'll also notice that I elected not to base `GrandParent` on a null parent reference but instead based on whether the `GrandParent` has any children which have children, applying real world domain semantics.

Comment: seems like a reasonable way but I am afraid of bloating my code with too much if else/switch case.   As I said, in most of the methods the child/parent/grandparent have different behavior, and I would rather solve it with method overriding on an application service (a method for each subtype) instead of one method with if else /switch case.